# how to mute specific statement from LogCat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, imasdk

I am getting an endless stream of

```
E/IMASDK: Received monitor message: getViewability for invalid session id:
```

and it's making it impossible to see any other log statement in my LogCat. Does anyone know how to mute such a specific nuisance?

Answer (score 0):

On the command line you can run something like

```
adb logcat IMASDK:S
```

to see log output but with IMASDK messages silenced. Android Studio also has support for filtering log messages. You can find it if you poke around in the UI a bit.